# C# Properties - Need Sub Properties

Tags: c#, xml, json, class, properties

I have been tasked with parsing out xml and json data into an application. I am trying to create a properties class that encompasses all the data I will be collecting.

Here is my issue/question

I have created a class with the variables for the weather data, temp, wind, uv index, etc. I have created the days as well. I can access the days individually but not as a whole. For example.

```
Monday m = new Monday();
m.TempHiF = "65";
```

What I want to do is this.

```
WDay d = new WDay();
d.Monday.TempHiF = "65"
d.Tuesday.TempHiF = "67";
```

And so on. I am pretty new to C# and I am not even sure what to google. I have been racking my brain for a week and come up with limited success. I am open to other suggestions on storing the data as well.

Comment: Do you understand OO concepts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is make WDay have properties for all the days:

```
public class WDay
{
    public Day Monday {get;set;}
    ...
```

Then have the `Day` class have a `TempHiF` property, and so on:

```
public class Day
{
    public string TempHif {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Make sure WDay's constructor initializes all its Day properties with new instances to avoid null reference exceptions.

Comment: Except you probably don't want temperature as a string.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out right after posting this. This is the method that I used.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Week {
  public Day Sunday{get;set;}
  public Day Monday{get;set;}
  // etc...
}



class Day {
// Define day-bound properties here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to nest your classes so that your weekday class has a monday class, a tuesday class, etc.. then give each of your day classes a TempHi property or whatever additional properties that you want and then just reference those

```
class WDay{

  public Monday mon = new Monday();
  public Tuesday tue = new Tuesday();
  public Wednesday wed = new Wednesday();

}

class Monday
{
  private string _TempHi;
  public TempHi
  {
    get {
     return _TempHi;
    }
    set {
     _TempHi = value;
    }
  }
}

class main
{
  WDay WeekDay = new WDay();

  WeekDay.mon.TempHi = "65F";
}
```